# Java - Security is ON but I still can send any request I want

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, credentials, google-account

I have weird problem. I implemented security in my application, login via Google Accounts.

My securityconfig class with overithed method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
}
}
```

And for example I wanted to test this endpoint:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Book addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
    bookService.addBook(book);
    return book;
}
```

I'm using Postman to do that and when I click SEND for first time I'm getting this error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-07-01",
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type '' not supported",
"path": "/book/add"
}
```

But in second attempt (and every next) I can add book to library even without credientals. What I've made wrong?

Comment: Is your `WebSecurityConfiguration` being loaded? Try to put a breakpoint in it to confirm. If not, did you perhaps put it in a package outside the base package being scanned?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your request? It states "Content type '' not supported". In postman, if you are sending data as POST data, in the body tab, default value is "Text", you will have to change it to "JSON"

Comment: I don't see the required enable annotation.

Comment: I'm sendig JSON and content type is set to json, as I said in second attempt everything works without login. But, when I leave my app on for some time and I don't send any request for a while, there is the same issue - first time after breake is with error, second and other works. This is ss of websecurity in debug mode: https://ibb.co/jO0w2J

Comment: I have added @EnableOAuth2Sso in main class and now I have 403 error, but I can't send request even with access token: https://ibb.co/d8J29y

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying any Authentication on API, you can put it on API as following, it works for me

### With accessing OAuth2 Authentication in method param:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Book addBook(OAuth2Authentication auth, @RequestBody Book book) {
    bookService.addBook(book);
    return book;
}
```

### With annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AGENT')")
@RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Book addBook(OAuth2Authentication auth, @RequestBody Book book) {
        bookService.addBook(book);
        return book;
    }
```